# Query a DataTable via Dynamic LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable and like to query via Dynamic LINQ.

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic.Core
...
Dim Values as DataTable
...
```

What works is when I simply select a specific column (named 'age'), for instance:

```
    Dim result = Values.AsEnumerable.AsQueryable.Select("age")
```

But now I want to filter the DataTable via a where clause and that does not work or I am not aware how to implement this correctly:

```
Dim result = Values.AsEnumerable.AsQueryable.Where("age > 60")
```

Here I got:

> "Binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for System.Object and
> System.Int32"

Okay, I understand the error message to some degree but I do not know how do I have to change my code accordingly.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I haven't tested it but the fact that getting a value from a `DataRow` always returns an object reference, you presumably have to cast/convert to the type of the actual data. In this case, my first options would be `"CInt(age)"`, `"Convert.ToInt32(age)"` and `"DirectCast(age, Integer)"`.

Comment: Try creating a strongly typed dataset/datatable instead. They're also querable without needing AsXXXable

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks a lot for this first ideas. The `"Convert.ToInt32(age)"` works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Linq to DataTable. `LoadCoffeeTable` returns a DataTable. Both Type and Name are String fields in the DataTable.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = LoadCoffeeTable()

    Dim result = From r As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
                 Where r("Type").ToString() = "Regular"
                 Select r("Name")

    For Each r In result
        Debug.Print(r.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @CaiusJard Does `Dim ColumnToTest = "Type"` 
        `Dim TestValue = "Regular"` 
        `Dim ReturnColumn = "Name"` and then using the variables in the Linq query make it dynamic? I will edit my answer otherwise please enlighten me.

Comment: This is "normal linq", dynamic in the sense that the developer can throw anything they like in, but static in the sense that once the program is compiled what the query looks for in its where and returns in its select is "baked in".. Dynamic is where the criteria for the query is expressed as a string that is parsed and run at runtime, rather than compile time. In essence your query will always only query coffee type and return the name. As dynamic it might look like `.Where("type = ""Regular""")`, but the crux is that the string could be a variable like `.Where(queryString)` - "so can mine"..

Comment: ..you might say, "look: ` Where r(whatColumnStr).ToString() = whatValueStr` but for a couple of things - this fixes the comparison to take place using strings and it's not truly dynamic because the fact that it compares only one column is baked in at compile time. The dynamic LINQ variable could easily be a string of `"type = ""Regular" && size > 2"` so it's truly dynamic, i.e "evaluated at runtime, rather than compile time"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it would neaten your life up a lot if you use strongly typed datatables. These are datatables that are generated by a designer, and have named, typed properties rather than everything being an object, accessed by a string

We make a strongly typed datatable by adding a DataSet to our project with the "add new item":

[image]

You can ignore that mine says C# - it's just what the project I was working in for some other qustion was using. The two languages are the same under the hood. Look for yours under the Data heading of your VB items

When you add it you'll get a surface, right click it and `Add >> DataTable`. Right click the datatable and `Add >> Column`, give the columns names and properties. Here with the Student and Classes, I've generated them by linking a database and dropping the database tables onto the designer, so I didn't create these manually, but you can. If you ARE working with a database, right click the surface and add >> TableAdapter instead, configure the connection and query and you'll get a datatable that mimics your database table. If you don't have a database, just create the table and columns manually - I did this with the "NotFromDb" table; for that one I richt clicked and Add DataTable/Columns. Even if you don't hav a DB and ar creating datatables "manually" it's still going to be faster, easier and better than writing statements like `Dim dt as new DataTable`, `dt.Columns.Add("Age", ...)` etc

So you'll end up with something looking like this:

[image]

That's it; your strongly typed datatables are ready! They're a lot nicer to work with than regular datatables. For example, to increment all the BlahInt in NotfromDB, the code would look like:

```
For Each r in notFromDb
  r.BlahInt += 1
Next r
```

The same in weakly typed datatables:

```
For Each r as DataRow in notFromDb.Rows
  r("BlhaInt") = DirectCast(r("BlahInt"), Integer) + 1
Next r
```

You can see I've made a typo in BlhaInt and Intellisense won't help me out because it's a string, not a full property name.. The code is also a lot harder to read, because everything is an object, accessed by a string and has to be casted to make it useful

All in, plain up datatables are a pain in the arse and I seldom use them, because strongly typed ones are so easy to create and much nicer to work with

---

Now, to the main point about dynamic:

My db has these values in (this is :

[image]

It's just test data but gives us something to work with. We'll do a dynamic for ClassID > 5

Here's a shot of my VS stopped in the debugger after executing the dynamic:

[image]

`this` in C# is the same as `me` in VB.. As noted, this is C# because it's what I had lying around; take a look at the `schoolDB.Where` which is the same as it would be in VB. `schoolDS` is the dataset my `Students` strongly typed datatable lives inside, hence the `schoolDS.` before the datatable name

I've assigned the results of the operation to the `dt` variable, C# `var` is like VB's `Dim`

So you can see.. It just works, and it's simpler and cleaner than using weakly typed datatables and having all the AsEnumerable AsQueryable blah

Comment: Thanks a lot Caius, really a great and comprehensive answer regarding strongly typed datasets. As I get the `DataTable` from another object (there is a toDataTable method implemented) I retrieve this untyped form. Guess I could transform the data by a `ForEach` into a DataTable by myself but I fear it is slower. But I will try.

Comment: An ST datatable is still a datatable at the end of it all, and can still be used by something that only understands weakly typed datatables. If your ST DT has properties `Name`, `Age` and `Address` then it can be handed to something that only understands how to access it by e.g. `Rows[0]["Name"]`, `Rows[0]["Age"]` and `Rows[0]["Address"]`. Hence if you can name your columns exactly the same as it will access by string, then give the STDT to the other device to fill with data, it works.. Note that if the other device creates a weakly typed DT and gives it to your then it is as you say.. you'll

Comment: have to copy the data out of it. Take a look at [Merge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=netcore-3.1) - if you set your STDT up to have the same schema as the WDT returned by the device, then you can probably merge them with a one liner. To give more advice we really need you to go up the rabbit hole a few steps and show the bit of code you didn't before (how it comes to be that you have this Values datatable in the first place). It might be that the whole ToDataTable() is an indirection, can be dropped, and you can Dynamic Linq the original source

Comment: The `Values` comes from a dll for accessing a SPSS file (software for data analysis; https://www.nuget.org/packages/SPSS.NET). `Data = Spss.SpssDataDocument.Open(file, Spss.SpssFileAccess.Read)` and then `Values = Data.Cases.ToDataTable`

Comment: So can `Data.Cases` be queried in some LINQy way? Or is the component's code available to provide a modified version that can be e.g. `Data.Cases.FillDataTable(dtSuppliedByDirk)` ?

Comment: Seems that `Data.Cases` cannot be accessed via LINQ. But it could that also source code is hosted on github so I could check for make adaptions accordingly. But I also have now created a copy of the data into a strictly typed DT. But strange enough it still does not work the way you described it. Also I have to add `AsEnumerable` blah blah to use the `.Where` clause which indicates also that there seems to be missing something. Is it correct that I got a strictly type DT in case all DT.Columns have a Type or do I have to set some more props to get it work?

Comment: Works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgqBp.png - did you perhaps erroneously try to call `.Where` on the `.Rows` property ? In C# this code will generate an error that mentions IQueryable: `strongDT.Rows.Where(...)` but this works: `strongDT.Where(...)` - in VB the error is different.. (It would be helpful for you to post the exact code youre using and the exact error youre seeing.. Right now you've just said "I wrote some code and I got an error and I had to do that thing that I did before" - and I'm like "what code, what error, what did you add?!" :) )

Comment: Did you add the rows to the strong DT, then mistakenly call the query on the weakDT?

Comment: I have created a DS DataSet1 via the database designer and added an empty DataTable named Values3DataTable (`Public Property Values2 As DataSet1.Values3DataTable` and `Values2 = New DataSet1.Values3DataTable`) I must add the cols during runtime so I use `Values2.Columns.Add(Var.Name, Type.GetType("System.Double"))`. To assign the values to the DataTable I use the non-typed DataTable called Values and run `Values2.Merge(Values)`. If I then try `Values2.Where("age > 60").Select("age")` for instance it does not work. –

Comment: *i must add the columns during run time* -- errr, yeah that's not really the point of strongly typed datatables! You are hard coding `"age > 60"` so you MUST surely be certain that you're going to have a column called `age` so you can certainly put an "age" column into your strongly typed table *in design time* in the DataSet Designer

Comment: You have to understand that to a big degree an ST DataTable is just a normal datatable with some niceties like compiled (done at design time and compiled by the compiler) properties that reference the data therein. Your st table row has an Age property that is an int and returns the result of `CInt(me("Age"))` for example; it's the compiler time property that makes binding nice and dynamic LINQ work out. If you add all your columns at runtime then it's not strongly typed!

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to stack overflow!!!

Try below points:

```
Include System.Linq.Dynamic
```

[where](http://ak-dynamic-linq.azurewebsites.net/Library/DynamicQueryable/Where)

[select](http://ak-dynamic-linq.azurewebsites.net/Library/DynamicQueryable/Select)

[query](http://ak-dynamic-linq.azurewebsites.net/Library/DynamicQueryable)

Comment: This is too vague to be an answer. Answers must address the specific question asked, not just give somewhere a place to look for the answer themselves.